# asp:FileUpload set filename using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm using a `<asp:FileUpload>` in a modal pop-up form that contains the detail of a DataTable row.

I need to set the filename and its path, that is in an a cell of the DataTable, in the FileUpload control when i click on the detail.

I'm using this instruction:

```
$('#<%=mailTemplateUpload.ClientID%>').attr("value", Template);
```

but it's not working.

P.S.: Template is a string containing the filepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are looking the jQuery selector for your FileUpload?

You should probably do something like

```xml
<asp:FileUpload ID="MyFileUpload">
```

And then your selector can be something like

```js
$("input[id*=MyFileUpload]")
```

Then you can surely add any attribute you want on it.

Comment: yes, you perfectly understand what I was looking for. I've tried your code and now it's working